# Yammer not accepting OAuth token token through header during post

Tags: post, yammer

I am currently trying to upgrade my application to send an OAuth token through as a header instead of through the query string as per their new requirements. When making a GET request with the OAuth token in the header, my request succeeds verifying a valid access_token. However when trying to make a post with the same token, I receive a 401 unauthorized. This post with the same access token succeeds when the access token is placed on the query string.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yammerurl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token;
request.Host = "www.yammer.com";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
```

This is my set up for posting that is receiving an unauthorized exception and below is my set up for the GET request that succeeds. Again both of them are using the same access token and both methods work when the access token is passed through the query string.

```
  string url = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1";
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + YammerAccessToken;
  request.Host = "www.yammer.com";
```

Does anybody know if my setup for posting is incorrect or if there is another parameter I need to add?

Comment: What URL are you trying to POST to? Is yammerurl in the first example set to the same url that you have in the second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are not specifying the HTTP verb GET in the second one?  This is how I accomplish it in PHP and it works fine...

I call this in my main php file...

```
$ymuser = yammer_user_by_email('myemail@test.com');
```

this function is in my inc file...

```
function yammer_user_by_email($email, $token = null){
    global $YAMMER_ADMIN_TOKEN;

    $user = yammer_api_get('https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/by_email.json?email='.$email, $YAMMER_ADMIN_TOKEN);

    return $user[0];

}
```

All of my http calls are routed through here, and the admin token is applied to the header...
    function yammer_api_call($url, $method = 'GET', $body = '', $token){

```
  if ($token == null) {
    if (!$_SESSION['yammer_token'] || !$_SESSION['yammer_token']->access_token->token) return false;
    $token = $_SESSION['yammer_token']->access_token->token;
  }

  if ($method == 'GET'){
    $opts = array('http' =>
      array(
        'method'  => $method,
        'header'  => "Host: www.yammer.com\r\n" 
            ."Authorization: Bearer " . $token . "\r\n"
      )
    );
  }else{
    $opts = array('http' =>
      array(
        'method'  => $method,
        'header'  => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            ."Host: www.yammer.com\r\n" 
            ."Authorization: Bearer " . $token . "\r\n"
            ."Content-Length: " . strlen($body) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $body,
        'timeout' => 60
      )
    );
  }

  $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
  $resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  //print($resp);
  $resp_obj = json_decode($resp);
  return $resp_obj;

}
```